# how to import videos using coredata?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am developing one app named safekeep.I have to import videos using coredata by converting into data.

```
if ([[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]) 
{
     NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
     NSLog(@"Q: video path: %@",[videoURL description]);

     self.videoData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
     if(self.videoData)
      {
        NSLog(@"data is present");
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObject *imagetblObj= [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"VideoData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [imagetblObj setValue:self.videoData forKey:@"videodata"];
        [imagetblObj setValue:str forKey:@"date"];
        NSError *err;
        if (![context save:&err]) 
         {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't save history item into coredata");
         }

        NSLog(@"data saved");
        [self videodatafromdb];
    }
}

-(void)videodatafromdb
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"VideoData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
NSArray *recordsData=[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
self.videoarray=[[recordsData reverseObjectEnumerator]allObjects];
NSLog(@"Array count is %d",[self.videoarray count]);
if ([self.videoarray count]>0) 
{
  [self createScrollViewvideo];
}
}

-(void)createScrollViewvideo
{
    NSLog(@"in create scrollviewvideo");
    //add views to scrolview
    int x=5;
    int y=17;
    for(int i=0;i<[videoarray count];i++)
    {
        UIImage *imag=[[UIImage alloc] init];
        UIView *videoview=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100)];
        videoview.tag=i;

        UIButton *userButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 100,100)];
        [userButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userVideoClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        userButton.tag=i;
        imag=[UIImage imageWithData:videoData];

        [userButton setBackgroundImage:imag forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [videoview addSubview:userButton];
        [self.scrollview addSubview:videoview];


        [userButton release];
        [videoview release];

        x+=104;
        if ((i+1)%3==0) 
        {
            y+=110;
            x=5;
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"10000in create scrollview");
    if (y+110>self.scrollview.frame.size.height) 
    {
        self.scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, y+110);
    }
    else
    {
        self.scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, self.scrollview.frame.size.height+60);
    }
 }
}
```

-(IBAction)userVideoClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"video clicked");

```
UIButton *button=(UIButton*)sender;

VideoData *videoobj=(VideoData *)[self.videoarray  objectAtIndex:[button tag]];

NSLog(@"video data is %@",videoobj);

VidoesVIewController *videoviewcontroller=[[VidoesVIewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VidoesVIewController" bundle:nil];

videoviewcontroller.videodata=[videoobj valueForKey:@"videodata"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:videoviewcontroller animated:YES];

[videoviewcontroller release];
```

}

Videos are not showing in sroll view.But When click on video file it is navigating. When image is set to button, image is showing in view.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot see that you add the movie players view or thumbnail to `videoview`.

Comment: Why you are using coredata for storing movie? You can store it in documents folder, etc and put in coredata url to it.

Comment: I am storing this movies in folder but getting this movies using coredata

Answer (score 0):

See my answer in:

[Can I access the files used for external binary storage in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222632/can-i-access-the-files-used-for-external-binary-storage-in-core-data/13497992#13497992)

I came up with a 'creative' solution (whether it best practice is anyones guess), but it will allow you to use Core Data to manage your files while still being able to access the REAL files by their path.

By using the 'Allows External Storage' option on a Binary field, you can allow core data to manage references to your files for you, abstracting out a fair amount of the busy work.