# Storing AWS S3 video for offline viewing in iOS mobile application

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have come across a few questions that have not pointed out any clear approach to this problem. I am developing an iOS mobile application that, in theory, would retrieve a video file from an AWS S3 bucket, and the user would have the option to download it for offline viewing.

Is this possible using Core Data? I have read that there are file size limits that could prevent a user from downloading a video with a large file size.

Comment: Hi there, I think we'll need some more info here. What is Core Data? How is your application accessing S3? Is it native mobile app or a web mobile app? What's your authentication look like (eg using Cognito)?

Comment: Hi Jared, my apologies for not being more clear. From what I have understood, Core Data is the iOS framework that allows the develper to interact with databases and have consistent data, my question was if that is possible to make it work offline with a video retrieved from S3. As for my authentication, Cognito is what I will be using with an OAuth login through Facebook. And this is a native mobile app developed with Swift! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes core data can be used to store the video files that the app retrieves from S3. The storage limitation will be based on the user storage capacity also there are easier solution then storing the complete video on core data since this impacts the performance.Check the answer on the link to understand the alternative  [Can I access the files used for external binary storage in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222632/can-i-access-the-files-used-for-external-binary-storage-in-core-data/13497992#13497992)

Comment: Hi Ali, thank you for the link to the alternative solution. From what I was able to see there, it seemed fairly simple. However, the person who wrote the answer said that that solution might not be acceptable with Apple's App Store. I am creating this app with the intention of it being released on the App Store, so is it confirmed that this is a safe approach to store the video as external binary data and access it directly? Thank you in advance.